# iterating through object elements javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, foreach

I am trying to understand this:

```
  function keyValue(array) {
  var modeObj = {};
  var i=0;
  // create modeObj
  array.forEach(function(num){

    if (!modeObj[num]) {
      modeObj[num] = 0;

    } 
    modeObj[num]++;

     console.log("1 list object keys "+Object.keys(modeObj));
     console.log("2 list object value "+Object.values(modeObj));
    i++;
    console.log("3 iteration num "+i); 
  });  
}
```

When iterating through an array [1,4,5,4,6,1], this is what is comming out:

```
1 list object keys 1
2 list object value 1
3 iteration num 1
1 list object keys 1,4
2 list object value 1,1
3 iteration num 2
1 list object keys 1,4,52 list object value 1,1,1
3 iteration num 31 list object keys 1,4,5
2 list object value 1,2,1
3 iteration num 4
1 list object keys 1,4,5,62 list object value 1,2,1,1
3 iteration num 5
1 list object keys 1,4,5,6
2 list object value 2,2,1,1
3 iteration num 6
```

If found in the literature that "Object.keys method is used for returning enumerable properties of a simple array." As clear from an array [1,4,5,4,6,1] the key 1, and key 4 are twice in the array.  If we check the values of all corresponding keys we can see that the key-value represents a number of occurrences of partical key. Keys [1,4,5,6], the values - 2,2,1,1.

In the first line, the new object is declared, then there is the iteration through the array which is sent into the function " keyValue()".  The array [1,4,5,4,6,1].

By the expression  "var modeObj = {};" just the empty object is declared.

if(!modObj[element]) checks if the object's key (the element) in the iteration is undefined or has some value.  If the key does not exists the value 0 will be added as a value to the current key in the iteration. Later, it will be changed to the value 1 by expression "modeObj[num]++;"

What I am not sure, is my interprettation of the expression **modObj[element]++;** I believe it could be interpreted in two staps:

The first step: **modObj[element]= modObj[element]**,

The second step: then **modObj[element]=modObj[element]+1**

This means that **modObj[element]** will increment the value of a particular key, if the key is unique, will add just 1 which will represent a number of occurrences of the key, if that is the second or any other occurances of the key will add 1 to the existing number of occurrences.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just try this code in the browser's developer tools.

The `modeObj[num]++` will create a KVP with `num` as the key and `NaN`(becuase there is no number there to increment... if the key DID exist with a valid number as its value then that number would increase by 1) as the value.

So `modeObj[1]` leads to `modeObj` being: `{1: NaN}`